Could not build flutter App ios in xcode as the error undefined symbols
ld: warning: Could not find or use auto-linked framework 'CoreAudioTypes': framework 'CoreAudioTypes' not found
ld: Undefined symbols:
OBJC_CLASS$_FLTGoogleMapsPlugin, referenced from:
in GeneratedPluginRegistrant.o
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
